# How do I know when to use if or switch statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to construct my `data` object base on my url params.

```
var $data = {};

if(params.assessmentId !== undefined){
    $data.assessmentId = params.assessmentId;
}
if(params.classroomId !== undefined){
    $data.classroomId = params.classroomId;
}
if(params.studentId !== undefined){
    $data.studentId = params.studentId;
}
if(params.courseContentId !== undefined){
    $data.courseContentId = params.courseContentId;
}

console.log($data);
```

I want to check if they're exist first, then set it accordingly.

Is what I have is good enough ?

Should I use a switch statement instead ?

Comment: Been wondering this myself.. curious about the answers. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Don't use switch for this

Comment: Do you have your particular reasons and would like to share ?

Comment: @loli : so a bunch of if is fine in this case ?

Comment: Switch is for when you are looking at a single variable's possible values through multiple if/else-if but this is not what you are doing.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with a bunch of `if`s. But as several of the given answers mention, you don't need any `if`s in this case.

Comment: What do you mean I don't need any `if` ? Just set them directly ... Do you mind elaborate more here or answer it.

Comment: @开发人员 try michael's answer and see the output

Comment: @jas he would if the order of the checks was important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is what I have is good enough?

Yes.

If you want it shorter, use a loop over the expected property names.

> Should I use a switch statement instead?

No. A `switch` statement has a completely different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A switch statement won't really work in your situation because you keep examining different keys. Switch works on a single value, so you might use it to do different things based on the value of courseContentId:

```
switch(params.courseContentId ) {
    case undefined:
        code block
        break;
    case 10:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use switch or if, but this code that will do the same, only better:

```
var $data = {};
var params = {};
params.assessmentId = 11;

for (var n in params) {
    $data[n] = params[n]
}
console.log($data);
```

You are only copying values from one object to another, so you can simply loop over it and your `$data` object will only receive values set in `params`.

Answer (score 1):

In your provided example you actually don't need the `if` statements all. Just assign $data properties as you're doing. If something in params is undefined it will not reflect on your $data object.

PS. A switch statement will not help you in any way. A switch statement is used to branch your code depending on multiple possible values of THE SAME variable. Not different ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only these number of cases then it looks ok !! but if you have many conditions to check then you would have a check, 
a jump to the next clause, a check, a jump to the next clause and so on.

On the other hand, With "switch" the JVM loads the value to compare and iterates through the value table to find a match, which is faster in most cases.

Note: A switch statement is not always faster than an if statement. It scales better than a long list of if-else statements as switch can perform a lookup based on all the values. However, for a short condition it won't be any faster and could be slower.